# Does iOS use a GUI, or another type of interface?

Tags: user-interface, ios

I'm a student, studying A level ICT.

Today we were revising computer interfaces for the upcoming exams, and my teacher was asked if iOS uses a GUI, but she said that iOS is a tricky one to classify, as it's actually menu-driven.

Is she correct?

Comment: Reason for the vote down?

Comment: It's neither - "iOS (previously iPhone OS) is a mobile *operating system* developed by Apple Inc." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS

Comment: "Cocoa Touch is a UI framework for building software programs to run on the iOS operating system (for the iPhone, iPod Touch, and iPad) from Apple Inc." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_Touch

Comment: @techie007 Well yes, but all operating systems have a UI, regardless of what it is for. I'm asking about interfaces here, not what OS stands for (aka, what I've known for 8+ years now).

Comment: @techie007 Again, you're not getting this. UI = User Interface. GUI, CLI, NLI, MDI, etc are all types of UI..

Comment: If you know it's an OS, then why would you ask if it's a type of user interface?

Comment: "The most common combination of such elements in GUIs is the WIMP ("window, icon, **menu**, pointing device") paradigm" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface#Examples

Comment: @techie007 I asked if it was a _GUI_, or a _MDI_ interface, not an interface in general..

Comment: Ok, perhaps explain what makes you think it's NOT a GUI?  And why do you think a Menu Driven Interface can't be a GUI?  PS, watch out for this: "MDI" = [Multiple Document Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface) :)

Comment: @techie007 Please read the question again... my ICT teacher and myself have a disagreement. I say that iOS is a GUI interface, she says it's an MDI; who's correct?

Comment: You could both be correct . . . GUI in some places, MDI in others (and CLI in others) . . . the UI is a layer on top of the OS itself . . . you can interact with it lots of different ways.  I think @techie007's point is that your question is like asking is Linux a GUI or a CLI?  Linux itself is neither - KDE/GNOME/etc provide GUIs, bash and other shells provide CLIs, etc.  The OS is not a UI, but UI's run on top of the OS . . .

Comment: IMO, you're comparing apple to oranges, even after I reworded your question. :) But, as I see by googling some "Learn ICT" pages, they seem to say a GUI is ALWAYS a WIMP design, which isn't true in my opinion.  But hey, I'll bow out of this, and wait for it to be closed (since it's off-topic for SU anyway).

Comment: @techie007 Behaviour like that isn't tolerated here... answer the question properly, or buzz off.

Comment: Buzzing off, SIR!

Comment: @techie007 Voting down my question, and getting others to vote it down will not do you any good. Reported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS is an operating system. It has a graphical user interface (GUI), which is one of many kinds of user interfaces, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface

I suppose iOS has also some kind of command-line interface (CLI), but I wouldn't know.

Comment: Well, her argument was that the Settings uses menus, so it must be menu driven. I'm not sure if her argument is valid or not, because if I program a Windows application that has just one menu, then according to her argument, it becomes a menu driven interface?

Comment: @zyboxenterprises - Her argument is wrong.  The bads in the context of this class she is right.  But iOS is a GUI based operating system.  It it wasn't GUI it would only have a comamnd line because it wouldn't have a graphical user interface.

Comment: @Ramhound: just nitpicking a little here: there are three paradigms of UI. Graphical, command-line and text-based. Many OS' of yore had command-line and text-based interfaces only, e. g. Netware. Granted, most text-based environments were shells running on top of the CLI, but that is true of many GUIs also, e. g. X.

Comment: @bjanssen Very true, I also know that many modern Linux GUIs are based off CLI. Take Gnome for example.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on bjassen's answer, both iOS and Android are [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system). An operating system is basically just a bunch of programs that allow you to run software without having to directly interact with the hardware it is running on. iOS and Android include a GUI as part of a way for the user to interact with the Apps that run on each platform, but they are much more than a just a GUI.

I would look at the definition of a [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface), because it basically means that you are using graphics as part of your user interface.

Comment: Well, her argument was that the Settings uses menus, so it must be menu driven. I'm not sure if her argument is valid or not, because if I program a Windows application that has just one menu, then according to her argument, it becomes a menu driven interface?

Comment: A GUI and being menu driven are not mutually exclusive. You could have an App that is menu driven, but is also graphical, so it would be a GUI that is menu driven. Being menu driven just means that it uses menus to go from step to step (depending on your definition). A menu driven interface could run on both a command line interface, or a graphical user interface.

Comment: I would argue that menu-driven would mean that the entire interface uses menus, not just a portion (for example, a bank machine). Windows would be a graphical user interface because it uses menus, but it is not driven by menus.